# Parallel processing and Entity Framework - lock items including EntityState.Added

Tags: c#, entity-framework, parallel-processing, entity-framework-6, locking

In my application, I'm processing items from one source to be sent to another, generating GUID ids used by the destination for some items, and saving those GUIDs to a database.

My table (`GuidMapping`) has a unique constraint on both GUID and item identifier (`ItemIdent`).

I only call `context.SaveChanges()` once during the program's execution, after all items have been processed.

(I should note here that only a single instance of this program will run at once, and this is the only program that interacts in any way with this database.)

Multiple of these source records may reference the same related item for which a GUID is generated. For example, `RecordA` and `RecordB` may both be linked to `RelatedItem1`. If no GUID is found saved in my database for `RelatedItem1`, I generate a new GUID for it in code.

I discovered rather quickly that this single `context.SaveChanges()` was causing a problem. When `RelatedItem1` was first encountered during `RecordA`'s processing, a record containing its GUID and identifier was added to the context. Then when `RecordB` was processed, `RelatedItem1` was not yet inserted into the *database table*, so another new record was created for it. Then when `context.SaveChanges()` was called, the unique constraint on the item identifier was violated.

So I made it check both the records already in the database and those in memory like so:

```
private static GuidMapping GetExistingForItem(MappingEntities context, string itemIdent)
{
    var existing = context.GuidMapping;

    var addedEntities = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context)
        .ObjectContext
        .ObjectStateManager
        .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)
        .Where (ent => ent.Entity is GuidMapping)
        .Select(ent => ent.Entity as GuidMapping);

    return existing     .FirstOrDefault(m => m.ItemIdent == itemIdent) ?? 
           addedEntities.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ItemIdent == itemIdent);
}
```

This worked as expected until I attempted to change from a regular `foreach (var record in source)` to a `Parallel.ForEach(source, record => ...)`. Then, of course,

I have tried locking the `context` alone, and the `context.GuidMapping` `DbSet` and `ObjectStateManager` together:

```
// only context
lock (context)
{
    // check GetExistingForItem()
    // ...
    // context.GuidMapping.Add(...)
}

// both the DbSet and ObjectStateManager
lock (context.GuidMapping)
lock (((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager)
{
    // check GetExistingForItem()
    // ...
    // context.GuidMapping.Add(...)
}
```

Neither of those had the expected effect of preventing the unique constraint violation.

Is there a way to access the entities only added in memory in a thread-safe manner?

Answer (score 0):

In your case I'd rather added a decorator over your context that would cache itemIdent-GUID values put into context and check the cache before executing the context itself (the underlying service).
This would be easier to manage, more straightforward and robust.

Dummy code for you to understand what the decorator is:

```
interface IContext
{
    int AddValue(object value);
}

MainContext: IContext
{
    public int AddValue(object value)
    {
        // ... db connection and obj population
    }
}

ContextCacheDecorator: IContext
{
    private readonly IContext _mainContext;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Guid> _map;

    public ContextCacheDecorator(IContext mainContext)
    {
        _mainContext = mainContext;
        _map = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Guid>();
    }

    public int AddValue(object value)
    {
        // if map contains, skip or whatever...
        return _mainContext.AddValue(value);
    }
}
```